# file_get_contents phase XML

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

Trying to run file_get_contents from http://66.85.14.212:7254

Anyone have any suggestions how I could do this to query specific values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting the value by given code(it's working properly.):-

```
<?php
$url="http://66.85.14.212:7254/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
//for single variable you can write 
echo $xml->Name;
?>
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? Exposing your ip and port like that is not the safest way of getting things done.

Comment: Dear Martian,
I had try to get value form your given link and as I have got the value I have shared my code with you nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the assist :)